# The Standard For Linking <h> Tag Elements

Tags: html

Is either:

```
<a href="#"><h1>text here</h1></a>
```

or

```
<h1><a href="#">text here</a></h1>
```

"correct". Is there any benefit of using the first one, it seems more logical to me. Perhaps from an SEO point?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<h1><a href="#">text here</a></h1>
```

is correct, as HTML does not allow a block element (`<h1>`) within an inline element (`<a>`) ([src](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3)). your first example will fail [validation](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input).

> Generally, block-level elements may contain inline elements and other block-level elements. Generally, inline elements may contain only data and other inline elements. Inherent in this structural distinction is the idea that block elements create "larger" structures than inline elements.

Answer (score 5):

Your second example is the only allowed structure. The first puts a block-level element inside an inline element and HTML does not allow this. Browsers may allow it, but it is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There ain't really much difference in this particular case. There are some things to point out though:

- `<h*>` are block elements, `<a>` is an inline element by default. As others pointed out, XHTML does not allow block elements in inline elements, so if you did not redefine their display style in CSS, `<a><h1></h1></a>` is invalid.
- `<a href="#"><h1>text here</h1></a>` is a link that can have multiple child nodes. In this case, it only has a `<h1>` child node, but nothing is stopping you from adding more.
- On the other hand, `<h1><a href="#">text here</a></h1>` is a header that can cave multiple nodes. You can add all sorts of child nodes to it, like labels, etc.

So this is basically a logical difference without any practical differences in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Additional note, although the former case works, its purely due to browsers being permissive. You may find via inspecting the internal dom tree that

```
 <a><h1>foo</h1></a>
```

gets broken into

```
 <a></a>
 <h1><a>foo</a></h1>
 <a></a>
```

And this can create *interesting* results. ;)